# How to Unit test WEB API Controller Exception using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, webapi

How to Unit test IHttpActionResult Exception InternalServerError with status code 500 and message

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid myId)
{
    try
    {
        var myaccount = await _myaccountService.GetMyAccount(myId);
        return Ok(myaccount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

Did try with Test method

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GeMyAccount_WhenThrowsException_ReturnsServerError()
{
    // Arrange         
    var exception = new Exception("Internal Server Error");
    var expectedResult = new List<MyAccount>
    {
        new  MyAccount
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Name1"
        },
        new  MyAccount
        {
            Id = "2",
            Name = "Name2"
        },
    };
    var myId = new Guid();

    //Act 
    var mockMyAccountService = new Mock<IMyAccountService>();
    mockMyAccountService.Setup(mock => 
    mock.GetMyAccount(myId)).Throws(exception).Verifiable();   
    var controller = new MyAccountController(mockMyAccountService.Object);

    //Assert
    var actualResult = (await controller.Get(myId) as 
    OkNegotiatedContentResult<MyAccount>).Content;       
       ?? var result = actualResult as ObjectResult;
       ?? Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, result.StatusCode);
       ?? Assert.AreEqual("Internal Server Error ", result.Value);
      mockMyAccountService.Verify(b => b.GetMyAccount(myId));
}
```

Not sure how to get the  Exception and status code 500  using Moq.

Comment: The try-catch in the subject under test is swallowing the thrown exception. The exception wont be accessible outside of action. To assert expected behavior you would have to assert the result as `InternalServerErrorResult` which is what is returned by the subject under test when the exception is thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was said by Nkosi the exception is swallowed by the try-catch block so you are not able to make any assertion against the exception.

But you can (and should) make assertion against the returned object.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GivenAFaultyMyAccountService_WhenICallGet_ThenItReturnsAnInternalServerError()
{
    //Arrange         
    var expectedException = new Exception("Something went wrong");
    var mockMyAccountService = new Mock<IMyAccountService>();
    
    mockMyAccountService
       .Setup(svc => svc.GetMyAccount(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
       .Throws(expectedException);   
    
    var sut = new MyAccountController(mockMyAccountService.Object);

    //Act 
    var actualResult = await sut.Get(Guid.NewGuid());

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actualResult, typeof(InternalServerErrorResult));
}
```

I've made the following changes to your test:

- I've renamed your test to align with the [Given-When-Then structure](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html)
- In this test case I'm only focusing on a **single** situation when the underlying dependency is malfunctioning, so I've get rid of everything which is related to the happy path

  - The happy path should have a separate test case
- I've made the mock `Setup` more generic by replacing the `myId` parameter to `It.IsAny<Guid>()`
- I've also replaced the `new Guid()` to `Guid.NewGuid()` because the former would create an empty uuid, while the later will generate a new uuid
- I've removed the `Verifiable` call because it is not really needed here
- The **Act** phase is when you make the actual call against a given method, not when you are constructing the controller, so I've moved the comment to the right place
- I've changed the variable name `controller` to `sut`, which stands for the [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)
- I've replaced your hard to read assessment logic to a simple type check

  - `InternalServerError` returns an [InternalServerErrorResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.internalservererrorresult)
  - MSTest's `Assert` class has a method called [IsInstanceOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isinstanceoftype?), which makes the type check more convenient

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this code

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        //arrange 
        //prepare your data for test

        //act
        async Task action()
        {
            //run your sut action
        }

        //assert
        var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(action);
        Assert.Equal("Internal Server Error", exception.Message);
    }
```